# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

When I compile this code in GHC, the program tells me "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)"

```
...
camino :: (Ix v,Num p) =>(Grafo v p) -> v -> v -> Bool 
camino  g o d 
    | d == o = True
    | otherwise = esta d (camino_rf g o d (adyacentes g o)
...
```

I think I'm using the correct identation. 
Thank's a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The line starting with `otherwise` has too few closing parentheses.